# Using multiple schema with Mongoose in the MERN stack

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I am brand new to MongoDB and am working on a personal project. I am using MongoDB as my database, Express and Node for backend, React for the front end and Mongoose. It is a basic company management system with 3 things it keeps track of: customers, vendors and inventory. I would like them to be completely separate collections in the same database and I am preparing to write my schema, however I can’t find anything on using multiple collections in the same project, let alone multiple schema. How would I go about this?

To reiterate, my question is how do I set up multiple schema in mongoose so that way I can access different groups of things that have no relationship to each other (I.e. something I could embed)

Comment: By project what do you mean? MongoDB doesn't have a fixed schema so you can literally dump whatever you want in any collection. Collection in Mongodb is like a table in SQL DBMS.

Comment: By project I mean what will eventually be able to run on a server and take POST and GET request. I know MongoDB doesn’t have fixed schema, but I have to make schema for it to work with the front end, don’t I? I need to be able to GET a customer from the front end, but it won’t expect the stuff that an Item(inventory) gets right? Is there a way to use multiple schema even if I have to do multiple collections? Maybe this is more of a mongoose question

Answer (score 0):

I am just going to do this the dirty way. I am making the schema in mongoose very large and putting all of the parameters in it. I am sure this isn't the cleanest way but it will work.